# How to get achievement "You are doing it right"?

Tags: factorio

**You are doing it right** : *Construct more machines using robots than manually.*

What it means precisely? Are belts and inserters considered as a "machine"?

Is there a place I can see the count of machines I already built early-game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer to the very same question on Reddit:

> you must use construction robots to build more structures than what
>   you have placed by hand

Source : [SkyKoli answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/factorio/comments/5a9mqn/you_are_doing_it_right_achievement/d9es0an/)

Then he shows his trick to do so really quickly. The complete post [can be found here](https://www.reddit.com/r/factorio/comments/5a9mqn/you_are_doing_it_right_achievement/).

Comment: Note that in this context, "structure" is anything that is placed in the world. If you left-click to place it, that counts for this achievement. Belts, inserters, assemblers, etc. I am not sure about vehicles, but considering that "Getting on Track Like a Pro" requires placing a locomotive in the world to trigger the achievement, vehicles _probably_ count for this one, too.